# Getting the return value in a stored procedure using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm using EF (in .Net 4.5) in my MVC project and using a stored procedure to get data. My problem is that I don't know how to get the return value while EF asks me to return a collection of objects. Here is an example :

```
  Param:
  @id                AS NVARCHAR(5), 
  @out_error_code    AS INT output, 
  @out_error_message AS NVARCHAR(200) output 
  AS 
  BEGIN 
  DECLARE @int_return AS INT 

  BEGIN try 
      SET @int_return = 1 

      SELECT * 
      FROM   dbo.something
      WHERE  id = @id 

      SET @int_return = 0 
  END try 

  BEGIN catch 
      SET @out_error_code = Error_number() 
      SET @out_error_message = Error_message() 

      RETURN @int_return 
  END catch 
  END
```

And this code is auto generated:

```
  public virtual ObjectResult<DetailEmployee_Result> DetailEmployee(string id, ObjectParameter out_error_code, ObjectParameter out_error_message){
        var idParameter = id != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("id", id) :
            new ObjectParameter("id", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<DetailNhanvien_Result>("DetailNhanvien", idParameter, out_error_code, out_error_message);
    }
```

Can I get `@return_value = 1` (means error) in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: After working with EF. My solution is set @int_return as a param output